# Can I draw a box which (dynamically) fills to the bottom of the page?

Tags: boxes

Is there a way to draw a simple box with width `\textwidth` and height so that it fills from wherever it is placed to the bottom margin of the page?

Comment: Which type of box do you want to create? Have you had a look at `\vfill`?

Comment: @TeXnician he means a visible frame, like \fbox

Comment: It can be done, but it isn't simple.  It involves measuring the distance to the bottom of the text area from the top of the box (using tikzpagenodes).

Comment: @TeXnician yep, I mean a visible frame, thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I still need to fine-tune some parameters, but here is an idea with vertical `\leaders` that seems to work:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*\@helper@hboxto@hsize[2]{%
    \hb@xt@ \hsize {%
        \vrule \@width .4\p@ \@height #1\ht\strutbox \@depth #2\dp\strutbox
        \hfil
        \vrule \@width .4\p@ % automatic height and depth
    }
}
\newcommand*\@helper@hrule{%
    \kern -.2\p@
    \hrule \@height .2\p@ \@depth .2\p@
    \kern -.2\p@
}
\newcommand*\boxcolumnfill{%
    \par
    \vskip \dimexpr \dp\strutbox-\prevdepth
    \@helper@hrule
    \@helper@hboxto@hsize{.25}{.25}%
    \nobreak
    \xleaders \vbox {
                \kern -.25\ht\strutbox
                \@helper@hboxto@hsize{.5}{.5}%
                \kern -.25\dp\strutbox
            }\vfill
    \kern -.25\dp\strutbox
    \nointerlineskip
    \@helper@hboxto@hsize{.25}{0}%
    \@helper@hrule
    \break
}

\makeatother



\begin{document}

With some text before.
\lipsum*[1]
Is the positioning affected by the presence of descenders?
% Uncomment this line to find it out: Qfgjpqy.
\boxcolumnfill

\lipsum[2]

Whole pages of boxes follow.

\newpage
\boxcolumnfill
\boxcolumnfill

Some more text.

\end{document}
```

---

## Addition

Here is another version of the code, that endows the `\boxcolumnfill` command with an optional argument, in which you can specify an amount of additional whitespace to be inserted above the top horizontal rule:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*\@helper@hboxto@hsize[2]{%
    \hb@xt@ \hsize {%
        \vrule \@width .4\p@ \@height #1\ht\strutbox \@depth #2\dp\strutbox
        \hfil
        \vrule \@width .4\p@ % automatic height and depth
    }
}
\newcommand*\@helper@hrule{%
    \kern -.2\p@
    \hrule \@height .2\p@ \@depth .2\p@
    \kern -.2\p@
}

% The user-level command; in the optional argument you can specify additional 
% whitespace to be inserted above the horizontal rule.
\newcommand*\boxcolumnfill[1][\z@]{%
    \par
    % Not yet sure: provide a legal breakpoint here, just in case the user 
    % passes an argument that is too tall?
    % \penalty \@highpenalty
    \kern \dimexpr \dp\strutbox-\prevdepth
                % The additional "\dimexpr" around "#1" is actually redundant 
                % here, but you know, Murphy's law...
                +\dimexpr #1\relax
            \relax
    \@helper@hrule
    \@helper@hboxto@hsize{.25}{.25}%
    \nobreak
    \xleaders \vbox {
                \kern -.25\ht\strutbox
                \@helper@hboxto@hsize{.5}{.5}%
                \kern -.25\dp\strutbox
            }\vfill
    \kern -.25\dp\strutbox
    \nointerlineskip
    \@helper@hboxto@hsize{.25}{0}%
    \@helper@hrule
    \break
}

\makeatother

\flushbottom % please note



\begin{document}

With some text before.
\lipsum*[1]
Is the positioning affected by the presence of descenders?
% Uncomment this line to find it out: Qfgjpqy.
\boxcolumnfill

\lipsum[2]

Some additional space above the rule,\\
without descenders.
% Now with descenders: Qfgjpqy.
\boxcolumnfill[\bigskipamount]

If used at the top of a new page, \verb|\boxcolumnfill| prints a box extending
to the full page height, but any additional space is ignored, even if specified.

\newpage
\boxcolumnfill
\boxcolumnfill[10cm]

This text should be on a new page.  Let's try it again:
\boxcolumnfill[10cm]

\lipsum[3-4]

Now, with an argument that is too tall for the available space:
\boxcolumnfill[15cm]

\textbf{Beware:} a negative argument \emph{is} honored!\\
without descenders.
% Now with descenders: Qfgjpqy.
\boxcolumnfill[-2\baselineskip]

Some more text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works pretty well - thanks :) How would I tweak the vertical "padding" between the leading para and the top of the box?

Comment: @Ben: It’s pretty easy, if you want so, to add an optional argument for specifying an additional amount of whitespace above the top rule; but I’ll postpone this to tomorrow!  (:-)  Or would you prefer a mandatory argument (you wouldn’t need to worry about the ensuing text beginning with `[`…)?

Comment: a hardcoded value is fine - I just want a bit more breathing room. No rush, and thanks for your help :)

Comment: Well, for a hardcoded value of, say, `3.14159mm`, just use `\kern \dimexpr \dp\strutbox-\prevdepth+3.14159mm \relax`.

Answer (score 2):

This is easy with `tcolorbox` package. `height fill` option creates boxes with height equal to the available space to the end of the page:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

With some text before.
\lipsum*[1]
\begin{tcolorbox}[height fill]
\end{tcolorbox}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{tcolorbox}[height fill]
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[height fill]
\end{tcolorbox}

\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{tcolorbox}[height fill]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]